# DLL into Buffer with mingw32-gcc vs gcc

Tags: c, gcc, memory, dll, portable-executable

I have successfully created a proof-of-concept program (client.exe) that will load DLLs into memory then allow the programmer to call the functions exported by that DLL. When compiled with `gcc`, it is a resounding success!

But, when I compile it using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`, it seems that something becomes mis-aligned and wrecks my program.

My gcc compile command:
`gcc.exe client.c -o client.exe`

My gcc compile command:
`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe client.c -o client.exe`

Code:

```c
FARPROC libLoadMemory(char *dllName, char *procName)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(dllName, "r");

    if (!fp) 
        { printf("[!] Failed to load library\n"); exit(-1); }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long int fpSize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    printf("[+] %s is %ld bytes\n", dllName, fpSize);

    char *dllBuffer = (char*)malloc(fpSize);

    fread((char *)dllBuffer, fpSize, 1, fp);

    // Prints "MZ" if all goes well
    printf("Magic Number: \n");
    for(int i = 0x00; i <= 0x01; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", dllBuffer[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    /* Load Libary and Get Proc Address here */
    /* Will return `fpSharedProc` if successful */

    return fpSharedProc;
}
```

I am not worried about the items in the /* Load Library and... */ portion because my issue is with the loading into memory portion with `malloc()` and `fread()`.

Everything seems to fall into place and works as intended when I compile with `gcc`. But my function to find the PE Signature fails when I compile with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`. When I look at the bytes, I notice that the PE Signature `50 45 00 00` is shifted one byte.

When I debug it, I clearly see that the `pImageNtHeader->Signature` is pointing to the `45 .. .. ..` byte instead of at `50 45 .. ..`, which obviously fails.

[image: gcc vs mingw32-gcc]

Now with all of that out of the way, here is my question(s):

- Is there a difference in a way that gcc vs mingw32-gcc write to memory?
- Is there a CFLAG or LDFLAG that I am missing?
- What am I overlooking?

Comment: Try `fopen` with `"rb"` mode

Comment: You have to be joking! That is EXACTLY what the issue was! You are a genius. Please submit this as an "ANSWER" so that I can accept it.